# ¿Qué "estructura" usar cuando se quiere copiar una tabla a una base de datos distinta en SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda con respecto a las diferencias que hay en las consultas para copiar una tabla a otra base de datos:

```
Select * 
into BaseDatos2.dbo.MiTabla
from BaseDatos1.dbo.MiTabla
Where fecha_reg between 'xxxx' and 'yyyy'--por ejemplo del 2009 hasta el 2016
```

o en su defecto:

```
Insert into BaseDatos2.dbo.MiTabla
Select * from BaseDatos1.dbo.MiTabla
Where fecha_reg between 'xxxx' and 'yyyy'--por ejemplo del 2009 hasta el 2016
```

El punto es que me ayuden si lo que está allí arriba está bien escrito, o hay que especificar los campos (leía por allí que es recomendable, pero en este caso son más de 60 campos, a parte los quiero todos), además de esto son demasiados datos, más de 10 millones, y quisiera saber cual sería la consulta más eficiente (si es que fuese el caso), y si hay alguna diferencia con respecto a lo que se copia (si es que hubiese llaves foráneas o índices), o tal vez me recomienden una migración de esa data (por ser demasiado) mediante el comando BCP etc.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, debes entender la diferencia entre tus dos consultas, ya que no cumplen el mismo objetivo.

La primera de hecho te dará un error, ya que la syntaxis correcta es:

```
SELECT *
INTO BaseDatos2.dbo.MiTabla
FROM BaseDatos1.dbo.MiTabla
WHERE fecha_reg between 'xxxx' and 'yyyy';
```

Esta consulta creará la tabla `BaseDatos2.dbo.MiTabla` con la misma estructura de columnas que `BaseDatos1.dbo.MiTabla`, e insertará todos los datos de la tabla original que cumplan tu condición `WHERE` en la tabla nueva. Hay que considerar que crear la tabla de esta forma **no** crea claves (primarias ni foráneas), ni tampoco índices.

Tu segunda consulta es:

```
INSERT INTO BaseDatos2.dbo.MiTabla
SELECT * 
FROM BaseDatos1.dbo.MiTabla
WHERE fecha_reg between 'xxxx' and 'yyyy';
```

Esta consulta inserta los datos de la tabla `BaseDatos1.dbo.MiTabla` que cumplen la condición del `WHERE` **en una tabla ya existente** `BaseDatos2.dbo.MiTabla`.

Sobre cuál consulta te entregará mejor performance, simplemente hay que considerar que básicamente hacen lo mismo, pero además de insertar datos debe crear una tabla.

Hay herramientas para cargas de datos masivos que están optimizadas para grandes flujos. Ya que estás usando SQL Server, entonces lo lógico sería que usaras SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) para esto.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, de hecho, la primera consulta es un "lápsus brutus" de mi parte, entonces básicamente la diferencia es que en la primera se crea la tabla en el proceso y el segundo se crea antes de hacer la consulta, me parece que esta última no es muy adecuada para el caso. y sobre los fk e índices se aplica para ambos ¿no es así?. Por último, ¿entonces me recomiendas usar otras herramientas para la migración de data?

Comment: @Fran.J Integration Services tiene 2 herramientas:  Asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server, y la de Crear Paquetes. En tu caso solo necesitas la del asistente. Revisa el link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms140052(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: @Fran.J A qué te refieres a que sobre las llaves e índices se aplica para ambos?, con la segunda consulta, insertas datos en una tabla que ya existe, y que presumiblemente ya tiene estas llaves e índices creada. Sobre usar otras herramientas, como decía anteriormente, depende fuertemente de tus necesidades de usuario. Mover 10 millones de filas por lo general es un volumen de datos pequeño, en el que no sería necesario usar más allá del simple `INSERT INTO`. Y sí, lo recomendable es siempre insertar datos en una tabla que ya existe

Comment: @Lamak ok, entiendo, claro si se tiene la tabla creada pues la haces "completa", de todas maneras para esto tendré que recurrir a la primera consulta para poder copiar la estructura en caso que no tengan alguna fk o índices usando el top 0. Lo que sucede con la cantidad de data es que noto que las consultas demoran de 40min a 1hora, ya que en total son más o menos 20 millones, y con las cláusulas las respuesta se extienden, pero si me dices que 10 millones es poco entonces me quedo con el `insert into`

Comment: Corríganme si estoy equivocado. Pero si vas a user `INSERT INTO` para insertar datos en una tabla existente, puede valer la pena eliminar las llaves e índices antes de cargar los datos, y volver a crearlos una vez ya cargados. Usualmente resulta en una gran mejora en el tiempo total que toma la carga de datos.

Comment: @Fran.J "es poco" es relativo, depende de la cantidad y tipo de datos de columnas; pero por lo general, no es un gran volumen de datos. Sí hay que considerar que insertar datos puede tomar tiempo principalmente por el crecimiento del log también. Sí es recomendable usar herramientas como SSIS, donde puedes usar `Fast Load`, que realiza un bloqueo exclusivo de la tabla a la cual estás insertando datos, obteniendo un performance mucho mejor

Comment: @sstan En efecto *puede ser* mejor deshabilitar llaves e índices al momento de cargarlos y volverlos a habilitar después de la carga. Pero eso es algo que debe probarse en el ambiente del usuario, comparando el performance con índices habilitados contra el performance de índices deshabilitados y habilitarlos después. No hay una respuesta segura sobre cuál es mejor

Comment: Estamos en acuerdo. Pero lo menciono porque esa es la otra diferencia significativa entre las 2 consultas en la pregunta que hay que tomar en cuenta, no solamente el hecho que uno crea la tabla y la otra no.

Comment: @sstan sí, gracias por tu comentario; en efecto es algo que debe considerarse en los procesos de carga de datos

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, acabo de ver la cantidad de registros de una las tablas que ya se habían copiado a la BD nueva, y pues no son 10 millones son 80 millones y eso que solo en dicha tabla se ha considerado desde el 2009 hasta el 2012. Entonces tendré que ver sobre alguna herramienta o asistencia como lo dijo alguien en los primero comentarios.